# LessCss call css class from html code

Tags: asp.net, html, css, less

I have a asp.net page this asp.net page changes color based on the application area 
there are 5 application area's each application area has its own color .

I need to change the color of the page based on the application area selected.
I need to use lesscss and reuse existing css to change the color .

Is it possible to call a less css class from the html passing it the color based on the applciation area . Or any other way ?

How do i go about this ?

Comment: You would probably have to create different classes (either by hand-coding or using mixins) and then use them like [here](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/lFmcu).

Answer (score 1):

You can create one less file that will define all your base styles that are dependent on color parameter and then, for each site area create a separate less file that will override the color and import the base file. You'll get a separate styles file for each area:

**styles.less:**

```
// Define default color value
@color: blue;
.foo {
    color: @color;
}
```

**red-styles.less:**

```
// import base classes 
@import "relative-path-to-base-styles\styles.less";

// override default value for color
@color: red;
```